# Automated UV unwraps... NOT Smart UV unwrap

Tags: modeling, python, texturing, uv, polycount

I was thinking, when do you guys suppose we'll get true and efficient automated uv unwrapping?. With A.I and machine learning i'm surprised a program hasn't surfaced that examines a model anything from fruit to vehicles, people etc. I mean think about it all someone has to do is feed a program various unwraps and let it learn from those correctly done, and i guess incorrectly done uv unwraps. I'm talking flawless unwraps of anything so people can speed up their workflow and just focus on the texturing. I mean because when you just enjoy modeling as a hobby there's so much to do after the modeling is done, You have retopologize, uv unwrap which can be so tricky that it takes you days just to get the unwrap right, bake high poly details into a lower poly model etc. Someone needs to create the end all solution to uv unwrapping.

Comment: Is this a question or a geature request?

Comment: Not a feature request, just a question. A question about a program that would without fail and flawlessly unwrap any mesh. I guess i'm asking if anyone has heard of anything such thing. I mean i'm starting to get the hang of uv unwrapping but a tool to automate it would be awesome. Mind you i mean a tool that gets it right the first time and requires no manual tweaking from the user. Any program atm still puts seams in places where they are not wanted and requires the user to make adjustments. So a tool that eliminates that is what i mean.

Comment: maybe the problem is that the correct way to do it will depend on the object and the purpose, pure logic can't always guess what will be the best way, plus you have a lot of addons that can help to achieve things like orthogonize the uv or rationalize the islands organization, maybe the foundation should implement more of these functions. I think some progresses could more easily be done in automatic weight for example